# Prove $\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{f(3x)}{\ln(1+4x)} = 2.25$ knowing that $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f(x)}{x} = 3$

Tags: calculus, limits

$f$ is defined on the neighborhood of $x=0$, $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f(x)}{x} = 3$. I need to prove that $\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{f(3x)}{\ln(1+4x)} = 2.25$.
I'm kinda stuck. I was thinking:
If I define $t = 4x$ then $\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{f(3x)}{\ln(1+4x)} = \lim_{t \to 0}\frac{\frac{f(3 \cdot \frac{t}{4})}{t}}{\frac{\ln(1+t)}{t}}$ and I know that $\lim_{t \to 0}\frac{ln(1+t)}{t} = 1$
but I'm still stuck with $\lim_{t \to 0}\frac{f(3 \cdot \frac{t}{4})}{t}$...
Help?

Comment: Then define a new variable to be $3t/4$, factor out the constant and then apply the limit you know

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint**

$$\frac{f(3x)}{\ln(1+4x)}=\frac 34 \times\frac{f(3x)}{3x}\times\frac{4x}{\ln(1+4x)}$$

I am sure that you can take from here.

Comment: If $\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{f(3x)}{3x} = \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{f(x)}{x} = 3$ then the answer is $\frac{3}{4} \cdot 3 \cdot \frac{1}{1} = \frac{9}{4}$ but can I assume that?

Comment: For the first term, replace $3x$ by $u$ and for the second term, replace $4x$ by $v$

Comment: Oh I see. Thanks!

Comment: That should do it! +1

Answer (score 0):

To continue from your last equation, you could use for example:

$$ \frac{f(3\frac{t}{4})}{t} =  \frac{\frac{3}{4} f(\frac{3}{4}t)}{\frac{3}{4}t}  = \frac{3}{4} \cdot \frac{f(\frac{3}{4}t)}{\frac{3}{4}t}. $$

And use  limit theorems for composite functions after that.